# Manage Sharepoint 2013 list email settings using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I am migrating a code written using server object model to CSOM. The server object model has code that deals with creating lists with incoming email enabled. It also has code to retrieve the email address of the list(s).

I want the CSOM equivalent of

while setting:

- list.EmailAlias = "abc@abc.com";

While retreiving:

- list.CanReceiveEmail
- list.EmailAlias

I have tried to find reference on official site and other literature on the internet but found nothing. That's why I have turned to SO for an answer.

Comment: If someone can help me please.

Comment: Hi Amar, have you checked the post below, if it is helpful, you could accept so that it will also help others in the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In csom List class, there is no property which equals to "CanReceiveEmail","EmailAlias", checked from Official document:

[List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee545367(v=office.15))

If you are using SharePoint On-Premise, you can create a web service with SSOM and call with Client Script:

[Create ASMX Service For SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-asmx-service-for-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks Jerry_MSFT for the confirmation. I have not got any leads from other sources as well. Seems like this is the only option left.